# How to shift single NA to bottom of column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have the following data frame:

```
example=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6))


     x     y
1    1     4
2    2     5
3    3     6
```

I want to delete a single value, from 1 of the columns, so I get this (which I achieved using `example$x[example$x==2]<-NA`):

```
     x     y
1    1     4
2    NA    5
3    3     6
```

But now I am stuck, because I now want to move the remaining values up, so that the NAs are at the bottom:

```
     x     y
1    1     4
2    3     5
3    NA    6
```

Ultimately I want to be able to do this for both columns, with single values in different rows, e.g.:

from:

```
     x     y
1    1     NA
2    NA    5
3    3     6
```

To:

```
     x     y
1    1     5
2    3     6
3    NA    NA
```

Hopefully someone has a simple solution! Thanks

Comment: What's the rationale for doing this?  A data frame is intended, presumably, to relate values in a row to each other.  By doing this, you're changing the relation where `x = 1` relates to `y = 4` to `x = 1` relates to `y = 5`.

Comment: My data frame is x= female IDs and y=male IDs. I need to match a female to a male depending on their relatedness, which is different for each possible couple). Once a female is chosen, I need to remove that individual from the column and all remaining IDs move up so there is no void.
I was hoping there was going to be an easy solution, but I maybe need to reevaluate how to use these values. Possibly not as one dataframe, but as separate.

Comment: The good news is that your question makes sense in the context you've provided.  The better news is that R likely has better approaches to doing your matching. The approach will depend somewhat on what your matching criteria are. That's probably a separate question from this one, however.

Comment: That's good to hear! This piece is only a small part of a large loop which subsets and selects individuals from a pedigree for breeding. I am very new to this kind of coding, so this was the easiest way for me to think how it might work. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You might take a look at the `Matching` package. It may allow you to automate this procedure depending on the criteria you use. It primarily uses metrics (distances), which  requires non-categorical variables, although you can specify exact matching on categorical variables.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `is.na` and subsetting `[`. Starting with this dataset.

```
example=data.frame(x=c(1,NA,3),y=c(NA,5,6))
example
   x  y
1  1 NA
2 NA  5
3  3  6
```

you run through each variable with `lapply` and take variables that not missing, and append to these the missing values at the end. Then feed this result back into the original dataset using `example[] <-`, which maintains the data.frame structure.

```
example[] <- lapply(example, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))
example
   x  y
1  1  5
2  3  6
3 NA NA
```

We can also use the newer (R 3.3.3) `grouping` function like this

```
example[] <- lapply(example, function(x) x[grouping(is.na(x))])
```

or `order`

```
example[] <- lapply(example, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])
```

In the last two, the key is to order on `is.na` rather than the elements themselves. This way you preserve the original order of the non-empty elements.

Comment: The author of the post mentioned he wanted to shift elements, not to sort them!

Comment: @DamianoFantini Who is *he*? ;-)

Comment: Haha, a she indeed, but no worries :) This works perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% 
   mutate_all(funs(.[order(is.na(.))]))
#   x  y
#1  1  5
#2  3  6
#3 NA NA
```

If the columns need to be dependent

```
example %>% 
        arrange_all(funs(is.na(.)))
```